# Facebook RSS feed for page returns error 404

Tags: facebook, rss

i was using this URL to get RSS feed of my page:
"https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id="
but it stops working.. Is there a new URL or an alternative to simply get RSS 2.0 out of my page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please use the StackOverflow search befor posting a new question. Have a look at the following question of today:

- [Facebook RSS feeds have stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204978/facebook-rss-feeds-has-stopped-working)

The RSS JSON feed has been deprecated since 28th of January 2015. See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_2_90_day_deprecations

> The Pages JSON feed (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=%2019292868552&format=json) is now deprecated and will stop returning data from Jan 28, 2015 onwards. Developers should instead call the feed edge on the Graph API's Page object: /v2.2/{page_id}/feed.

Answer (score 1):

The good news are:

```
We are restoring the Page RSS feed immediately. The fix should be deployed in the next 24 hours and I'll let you know as soon as the RSS feed is functional again.
```

And the bad:

```
Please note that we will be deprecating the Page RSS feed in the first half of this year. We'll announce a 90 day breaking change as we did for the Page JSON feed.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1539780319626180/
```

So its possible to use the service again, but for a limited time