# Retrieve facebook wall with actionscript?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-wall

I'm looking for an easy solution to retrieve the posts / the wall of a facebook page with the help ActionScript 3. 
We need to retrieve the wall / posts from a specific Facebook page and display them in our swf. The key word is **retrieving**. It has nothing to do with posting to the Facebook page.

I'm aware of the Adobe dev tutorial on http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/getting-started-with-facebooksdk-actionscript3.html but as our solution won't be displayed in a traditional browser I seriously doubt that we can use JavaScript as an intermediary.

And just to make things clear, we are not developing an iOS- or Android-app (or any other mobile app). If we were I'd simply use Milkman Game's ANE.

Any ideas or solutions are welcome :-)

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/yourpalmark/facebook-actionscript-api ?

Comment: No I haven't tried it. I'll have a look at it, but it's 4 years old so I doubt it works with the new facebook api...

Comment: Reading `/page-id/feed` will need an access token. Getting the viewing user to log in seems out of the question from your description, so a page access token would be the alternative – but that should never be included in client-side code, because it could easily be stolen from there. So I think your only proper alternative is to implement reading the data server-side, and have your flash read it from there. Or maybe use the RSS feed instead (`https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id={page-id}`) – AFAIK that doesn’t need an access token.

Comment: I've been googling around for a few hours more and got my hopes up when i found the RSS feed you mention. Unfortunately the Rss feed will be deprecated within a few months as per a Facebook announcement https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1539780319626180/ 
Bloody stupid if you ask me. This means I have no choice but to use a page access token. Fortunately security is not an issue as the swf will not be accessible outside our own system. The good part is that I can get a JSON feed as described by this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204978/facebook-rss-feeds-have-stopped-working